# Python: appending a row in a csv file cause it to be split randomly

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a python (3.7) function that takes a string and append it to a .csv file. Here's the code:

```
def write_to_file(row):
    print("row: ",[row])
    with open('output.csv', mode='a') as output_file:
        output_file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        output_file_writer.writerow([row])
```

When I print the row I have results like:

```
row:  ["Introducing company, the tool that let's you manage your coins alt-coin on coinbase-pro, and many other exchanges automatically."]
```

but the .csv that it writes looks like this:
[image]

The funny thing is that if I copy the output of the print and I hard-code it in the `write` command, like this:

```
                output_file_writer.writerow(["Introducing company, the tool that let's you manage your coins alt-coin on coinbase-pro, and many other exchanges automatically."])
```

The .csv file is correct. What am I missing?

Comment: The code is correct. What was the tool you use to open the csv file? Please try to open it in a vanilla editor.

Comment: You were right, on numbers the file looks messy but on Excel it looks as it should! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to use newline='' inside open() , i.e. `with open('output.csv', mode='a', newline='') 
as output_file:`

as quoted from python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):

> If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n
>   linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be
>   safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own
>   (universal) newline handling.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it didn't work the problem was Numbers, on Excel the file looks fine!